# Как добавить запятую в конец списка Python

Tags: python, list, dict

Вообщем, есть просто список названий полей:

```
fieldnames = ['ID', 'TITLE', 'HONORIFIC', 'NAME', 'SECOND_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'BIRTHDATE', 'COMPANY_TITLE']
```

Как добавить просто запятую после последнего элемента списка? Чтобы было вот так:

```
fieldnames_new = ['ID', 'TITLE', 'HONORIFIC', 'NAME', 'SECOND_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'BIRTHDATE', 'COMPANY_TITLE', ]
```

Замечу, что не так (когда применяем append\extend(пустой элемент)):

```
fieldnames_wrong = ['ID', 'TITLE', 'HONORIFIC', 'NAME', 'SECOND_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'BIRTHDATE', 'COMPANY_TITLE', '']
```

Нужно для работы с динамическим словарём.

Comment: Зачем вам это?.

Comment: покажите как вы "wrong" список получаете. [mcve]

Comment: создать свой класс, унаследованный от list и переопределить __str__()?

Comment: Какая от этого польза? Сам список от этого не изменится.

Comment: Поясните, что значит "Нужно для работы с динамическим словарём."? Дополнительная запятая перед закрывающей скобкой при выводе списка в строковом виде на работу списка никак не влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Список - это *объект в памяти*, а НЕ его *представление* в виде

```
[element1, element2, element3]
```

Такое представление есть только:

1. *Синтаксис* для задания списка в программе - тогда вы можете его задать как

   `[element1, element2, element3]`

   так и

   `[element1, element2, element3, ]`
2. *Cтандартный вид вывода списка*  функцией `print(list_name)`
   (или командой `print list_name` для Python 2.x). В том случае его вид будет

   `[element1, element2, element3]`

То значит, когда вы хотите вывести список *с добавленной запятой*, вам нужно конвертировать его на строку, например так:

```
fieldnames = ['ID', 'TITLE', 'HONORIFIC', 'NAME', 'SECOND_NAME', 'LAST_NAME',
              'BIRTHDATE', 'COMPANY_TITLE']

list_with_comma = '[' + ', '.join(fieldnames) + ', ]'    # см. "Объяснение выражения" 

print(list_with_comma)                                   # Только тест
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [ID, TITLE, HONORIFIC, NAME, SECOND_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDATE, COMPANY_TITLE, ]
> ```

---

**Объяснение выражения** `'[' + ', '.join(fieldnames) + ', ]'`:

Это соединение 3 части (строк) - применением оператора `+` между ними:

1. `'['` - это начальная квадратная скобка(`[`),
2. `', '.join(fieldnames)` - соединение (`join`) елементов списка `fieldnames` со строчкой `', '` (запятая с пробелом) между соседними элементами,
3. `', ]'` - заключительная запятая (`,`), пробел () и квадратная скобка (`]`).

Comment: `str(list())[: -1]+", ]"` так разве не проще?